# VBNET Got error from changing image path in listbox

Tags: vb.net

I am stuck and don't know what to do,
I am trying to make an `image viewer`, and place all path of the `image` by folder in a `listbox`,
then when I try to select in the list of `index 2`, I got error and it said **"OutOfMemoryException"**

here is my code

```
Public Class Form1
Dim myimg As Array
Private Sub img_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles img.Click
    If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        myimg = IO.Directory.GetFiles(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(myimg)
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Me.Refresh()
    Me.BackgroundImage = Nothing
    Me.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
End Sub

Private Sub min_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles min.Click
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
End Sub

Private Sub max_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles max.Click
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
End Class
```

the error is located here

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Me.Refresh()
    Me.BackgroundImage = Nothing
    Me.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
End Sub
```

, please help
Thanks :)

Comment: Do you need to Refresh? Or have you tried removing refresh? Are you sure it is the problem? Because the img_Click event could also be a suspect considering it GetFiles (which could be very large) from a specified folder.

Comment: What is the size and dimensions of the image you are trying to load?  It is possible the image is just too big...

Comment: thanks,  but look like I found the problem, and it is come from "desktop.ini" that I try to show as image, how can I filter all images in a folder to be add in the listbox as a path list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't have a valid image file in the list.  Look for the exception:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                                          Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
  Try
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
      Me.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
    End If
  Catch ex As OutOfMemoryException
    'not a valid image file
  End Try
End Sub
```

To filter the list, you can do something like this:

```
Using fbd As New FolderBrowserDialog
  If fbd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
    myimg = IO.Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath).Where( _
                         Function(x) x.ToLower.EndsWith("bmp") _
                                  Or x.ToLower.EndsWith("png")).ToArray

    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(myimg)
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
  End If
End Using
```

Comment: I have try it and the exception works, thanks but the problem is come from "desktop.ini"

Comment: @Bondan'sBlackkDiamond Updated post to show a way to filter the files in your list.

Comment: Wow it works, and I adding or for jpg. Can you explain the way how to use the "Function(x)" ?

Comment: @Bondan'sBlackkDiamond Lambda function.  The `x` represents each file in the list and we're telling it to only return the files "where" the extension matches "bmp", etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is where your problem probably starts :

```
Private Sub img_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles img.Click
  If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
     myimg = IO.Directory.GetFiles(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
     ListBox1.Items.AddRange(myimg)
     ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
  End If
End Sub
```

So, before they select from your `ListBox`:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
  Me.Refresh()
  Me.BackgroundImage = Nothing
  Me.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
End Sub
```

Why not limit the size of images that could be shown in your `ListBox` to say **5MB**, like:

```
Private Sub img_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles img.Click
  If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
     myimg = IO.Directory.GetFiles(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
     For Each imgfile As String In myimg
         Dim allowedImgFile As New System.IO.FileInfo(imgfile)
         If ((allowedImgFile.Length / 1024) <= 5) Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(imgfile)
         End If
     Next
     ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
  End If
End Sub
```

You need to inform your user though that only images that are 5MB or less (or whatever size you like) will be displayed on the List.

Comment: but I use "sample image" folder (for testing) in my picture, all images is very light in size. any other way to view the image without a listbox?